# Regular build works fine, but signed build errors on EXPECTED RESOURCE OF TYPE ID

Tags: android, apk, android-resources

When I build my app regularly, it builds with no errors.   When I try to build the SIGNED APK, I get an error...

> Error: Expected resource of type id [ResourceType]

The line of code that is flagged is...

```
tv = (TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimestamp);
```

That ID is defined in the corresponding layout xml as follows:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="5dp"
   >

   <!-- Clock -->
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="12dp"
       android:layout_height="12dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_clock_white"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvTimestamp"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
       />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Not sure why this one is erroring out.

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Did you try clean build option?

Answer (score 0):

That is not a compiler error, it's a lint warning.

To solve it, try one of the following:

- Clean your project and sync it again
- Use `View.generateViewId()` to set an arbitrary id
- Create an `ids.xml` file in `res/values/`

If the debug version is running correctly on the emulator/physical device then you can safely go ahead and suppress this warning by:

- Clicking on the error and selecting **Disable error**
- Adding the following lines in `build.gradle`

  ```
  android { 
     lintOptions{
           disable "ResourceType"
     }
  }
  ```